# How to close collapse on clicking on a button using vuejs and quasar?

Tags: vuejs2, quasar

I'm using `<q-collapsible>` tag for a collapse action. That is working fine. But I need to close the collapse by clicking some other button through Vue js only.

Since I'm using quasar it has some functionalities like open() and close() and I don't know how to implement it. So if possible someone helps me how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done easily since quasar provides this functionality out of the box.

First, reference your quasar component

```
<q-collapsible ref="myCollapsible">
   ...
</q-collapsible>

<button @click="toggleCollapsible">toggle collapsible</button>
```

Then, execute the needed method

```
methods: {
  toggleCollapsible () {
    this.$refs.myCollapsible.toggle()
  }
}
```

This is for `toggle`, you can do the same with `open` and `close`.

Comment: Thanks. I used this. But I am getting an error like: Cannot read property 'myCollapsible' of undefined.

Comment: @Darshantheerth sorry I was missing a `$` .. it is `this.$refs` not `this.refs` .. it should works now .. otherwise let me know